# How to get sequence start value from another table's max value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

I'm trying to insert a bunch of values in a table but it doesn't have IDENTITY column, and I need to insert a unique value in that field. 
And the sequential number should be start based on the previous value present in that same field.

lets say I have a table like this

```
create table testTable (id int, fieldA varchar (20))
insert into testTable 
values (6,'Nick'),(7,'Tom')
```

Now the next value I insert in ID field should take be 8 and next row should be 9 and so on...

And below is the sequence I created; and is not working

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testTable_seq
declare @maxy int = ((select max(ID) from testTable) + 1)
START WITH @maxy
INCREMENT BY   1
```

I expect the below insert should get the next value from the sequence I created or just tto get the next sequential number from  previous ID field

```
insert into testTable 
values (testTable_seq.next value,'Harry')
```

Comment: Make ID column as auto increment. Then you don't need any manual task to generate IDs

Comment: I can but the problem is there are data inserted from other sources with unique values for that ID, so I couldn't make it as auto increment

Comment: You could build a valid `create sequence` statement, as explained by Sami, and then use [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to create the sequence object.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that, if you see the arguments in the docs **[`CREATE SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)** it already stated that the value of `START WITH` should be a constant value, same as `INCREMENT BY`, `MINVALUE` and `MAXVALUE`

> START WITH constant

I don't understand why you want to create a `SEQUENCE` to insert values into a table, and also `MAX()` won't do as you expect, instead you can simply

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  AColumn VARCHAR(20),
  CONSTRAINT PK_TestTable_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Comment: I can but the problem is there are data inserted from other sources with unique values for that ID, so I couldn't make it as auto increment  Is there any other way to do achieve this?

Comment: @Mar1009 Alright, let's say you can, what happens if the table is empty? `SELECT MAX(ID) + 1` isn't a way you can take.

Comment: Thansk for your responnse @Sami, However this table will never be empty at any cost, this will only have insert data operation in this table.

Comment: @Mar1009 There is no need to do so, just use `IDENTITY` and let the system do it for you.